# Tkinter Wait for Multiple Button Presses

Tags: python, tkinter, wait

Have created a calculator with, among others, y^x and it uses wait command to wait for x value to be pressed.  Wait only waits for one button press.  Would like it to wait for at least 5 button presses, such as -25.3.  How to do this?

```
# Create a wait function that will wait for another key press
def wait_variable(self):
    self.tk.call('tkwait', 'variable', self.equation)

def power(self):
    a = self.get_expression()
    self.equation.set(f"{a} ^ b (enter b)")
    # Call the wait function
    self.wait_variable()
    b = self.get_expression()[-1]
    power_expression = f"math.pow(float({a}), float({b}))"
    _expression = self.get_expression()
    self._calculate_expression(power_expression)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest that you create a global variable and increment it with every button press, then create a function that gets called with every press and checks the value of the variable, if the var had the value of 5, execute stuff, I hope that helps.